# Separation of mind and consciousness/soul

Tags: subjectivity

I heard phrases like

> My brain is telling me ..., but i know ...

For example:

> My brain is telling me to stay with him/her, but I know that it's not
>   the right thing to do.

It sounds like people have a separation between their brain and something else that they think is *them* / something that defines as *them* (maybe their consciousness or soul).

I want to know if there is a name for that. I think it is similar to the "Who am I?" question.

Comment: This is called [Cartesian mind-body dualism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind%E2%80%93body_dualism), and, in a more primitive form, the [homunculus fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homunculus_argument). People imagine a "little man in the head" which is "them", as opposed to the big physical man with the head attached.

Comment: Plessner called it ex-centric positionality, the human subject being non-spatially positioned within its physical body and at the same time outside of its living/experiencing body, thus having distance to its own self, allowing for conscious experience of the empirical self. There is nothing paradoxical about the human being a physical body, a body that feels and lives, and a self which at the same time is both and not identical with them. That's the human condition. People saying they *are* their brain simply talk nonsense. Yet, this does and should not fall apart into dualities.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! That's what I was looking for